# FontLab Studio and font editing

Tags: fonts, fontlab-studio

I have [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63695/fontlab-studio-and-font-editing#comment135424_63695) problem, how i can solve?

Answer (score 1):

The general workflow is to open your existing fonts, save your working files as .vfb and export new OpenType fonts. There are quite a few potential issues you need to check for before doing this though.

I would suggest you read [the manual](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/download-fontlab-studio/) in detail.

(And to be cynical, I'm not convinced that someone who would spend US$649 on an application of this complexity wouldn't have worked through this issue).

Comment: thanks! this "Font \l_tmpb_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters" error what could be caused?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: don't worry! the last thing, tell me if this workflow is right to exchange characters between the Asana Math and the Latin Modern Math Fonts. 1: open the .otf file in fontlab 2: copy the character from Asana Math that i want to exchange and paste it into the Latin Modern Math in the corresponding position, (on the same character but in the Latin Modern Math font) 3: save the modified font as .vbf file 4: open it in fontlab and using the generate font command generate the .otf file than rigth click on it and install.

Comment: Did you really spend US$649 on the software?