# What is the best .otf file editor? In your opinion

Tags: fonts, fontlab-studio

What is the best .otf font file editor ? i have try font lab studio but i can' t save in .otf file...

Comment: There is no 'best'. They all have different pros and cons. Try a few out. THere's FontLab's products, Fontographer, Glyphs, FontForge, and others...

Comment: thanks ! and with this editors how i can save in .otf ? in the save as command there is not this options

Comment: Voting to close. One question is too broad; the other is trivial and doesn't show research effort (even though I have answered it)

Comment: Also, the problem seems to be solved judging from this later question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/fontlab-studio-and-font-editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FontLab, File menu > Generate Font.

This is probably not available in the demo version: "[Demo limitations: export and save limitations](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/download-fontlab-studio/)."

The manual, [available from the same page](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/download-fontlab-studio/), covers "Generating OpenType Fonts" in the full version, starting on page 877.